# Find $d\left(\frac{\partial\left(x,y\right)}{\partial\left(\delta_1,\delta_2\right)}\right)$ with the exterior product

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $J_{\delta_1,\delta_2}^{x,y}$ denote the Jacobian $\partial\left(x,y\right)/\partial\left(\delta_1,\delta_2\right)$.

Suppose I wanted to find $d\left(J_{\delta_1,\delta_2}^{x,y}\right)$ (considering only the matrix of the Jacobian, not the determinant part) with the exterior product. I [have read](http://neutrino.aquaphoenix.com/ReactionDiffusion/SERC5chap7.pdf) that, with the exterior (wedge) product, it might be possible to write this as
\begin{align}
d\left(J_{\delta_1,\delta_2}^{x,y}\right)=d\frac{\partial x}{\partial \delta_1}\wedge d\frac{\partial x}{\partial \delta_2}\wedge d\frac{\partial y}{\partial \delta_1}\wedge d\frac{\partial y}{\partial\delta_2}
\end{align}
Is this right? I'm new to this concept..

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. If you view $J^{x,y}_{\delta_1,\delta_2}$ as a matrix-valued function of $(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, then its differential should be a matrix-valued $1$-form. But what you've written is a scalar-valued $4$-form.

Comment: @JackLee Ahh I see, I will go back and keep reading. Thank you for your comment.